# Apply embedded fonts to special characters in spark textArea using TextLayoutFormat

Tags: apache-flex, textarea

By setting fontfamily directly to textarea in mxml fonts get applied to special characters. But using tlf and setting fontfamily it does not apply.

style.css ::

```
@font-face

{

    src: URL("/Assets/Fonts/GandhariUnicode-Bold.otf");

    fontFamily: "GandhariUnicode-Bold";

    embedAsCFF: true;

}
```

snippet of source code ::

```
textArea.textFlow.interactionManager.selectRange(beginIndex, endIndex);

var textLayoutFormat:TextLayoutFormat = getTextLayoutFormat();

textLayoutFormat.fontLookup = FontLookup.EMBEDDED_CFF;

textLayoutFormat.fontFamily ="GandhariUnicode-Bold";    

textLayoutFormat.renderingMode = RenderingMode.CFF;
```

Answer (score 0):

Embedded fonts can behave strangely. I see you're using a bold font, have you tried also setting explicitely font weight to bold when embedding you font or/and on the TextLayoutFormat object?

Also, I've found this thread wich migh be useful : http://forums.adobe.com/thread/635711

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just setting the fontFamily and that's it? Add the normal font weight definition as well and see what changes.

Comment: Did you set the fontWeight? http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf6320a-7fec.html